# How should be the connection string be written in MVC 4

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I have just installed the Visual studio 2012 Express edition for web and I am trying to connect to localdb in a Mvc 4 project.

In Sql Server Management Studio, I am able to successfully connect like this:

[image]

And my connection string (in application) looks like this:

`connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf"`

However, I am getting an error telling "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible."

Any ideas what is wrong over here ?

Comment: How about just `Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;` ?

Comment: This should do it:                                         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI"

Comment: @Ofiris I tried both. Didn't work :( But I am able to connect with `sql server management studio`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Integrated Security` as `True` as explaind in [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string), for sample:

`Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True`

Make sure the Sql Server service is running on the machine.

On the other hand, you could check the [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/). It is a good website to found the right connection string for each diferente scenario.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for being naive. But I went to `services.msc` and there is nothing called as a `sql server` in it. Any thing wrong ?

Comment: But the `sql server management studio` is able to connect with the database. But from the application I couldn't connect

Comment: You are connecting local DB file (test.mdf) so sql server is not required.